# Linux tr command with punctuation

Tags: linux

I need to use the tr command to translate for ROT13, (moving along 13 characters in the alphabet) for both upper and lower case

This is what I have come up with

```
tr "A-Za-z" "N-ZA-Mn-za-m"
```

However it now also needs to translate for the punctuation characters.

I've seen someone mention that

```
[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"'/$]*
```

would help me, but I honestly have no clue how to add this into my code.

I am completely new to linux!

Comment: What does the translation map for the punctuation look like?  You have to have some known character order for your translations to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly how you define "rot13".  I believe this is sufficient:

> http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2563
>
> If you read the International Obfuscated C Code Contest
>   (ftp://ftp.uu.net./pub/ioccc/), you frequently see that part of the
>   hints are coded by a method called rot13. rot13 is a Caesar cypher,
>   i.e., a cypher in which all letters are shifted some number of places.
>   For example, a becomes b, b becomes c, ..., y becomes z, and z becomes
>   a. In rot13 each letter is shifted 13 places. It is a weak cypher, and
>   to decipher it, you can use rot13 again. You can also use tr to read
>   the text in this way:
>
> `tr a-zA-Z n-za-mN-ZA-M`

Note, too, that the quotes (") are only needed if a string argument has a blank in it.  Since you don't have any blanks in your "tr" arguments, the quotes aren't needed.  These two statements are functionally identical: `tr "A-Za-z" "N-ZA-Mn-za-m"` == `tr A-Za-z -ZA-Mn-za-m`